# The object of type GameObject has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity

I am instantiating the prefabs time to time and I want them to be destroyed with in 2 to  seconds as well. But I am getting the error that says:

```
The object of type GameObject has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it
```

So, somewhere script to trying to access the prefab even after it has been destroyed so probably I need to relocate the the statement where I am destroying the prefab using `destroy` .

Here is my code:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (!spawning) 
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
        }
        time = Random.Range (20, 40);
        if (timer >= time)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Spawn());

        }
        }
    public IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        spawning = true;
        timer = 0;
        initial = new Vector3 (Random.Range(rmin, rmax), -0.23f, Random.Range(r.renderer.bounds.min.z, (r.renderer.bounds.max.z + 20)));
        fuelprefab = (GameObject)Instantiate (fuelprefab, initial, Quaternion.identity);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds (Random.Range (1, 3));
        spawning = false;
        Destroy (fuelprefab, Random.Range(1,3));
    }
}
```

What change do I need to make so that it's not accessed after it hs been destroyed and the newly instantiated prefab is accessed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `fuelprefab` is the object passed to the Instantiate() command:

```
fuelprefab = (GameObject)Instantiate(fuelprefab etc.
```

Thus the code attempts to instantiate that object after destroying it. So what you want to do is have separate variables for `fuelprefab` and `fuelInstance`. Then you can freely Destroy() the latter while never destroying the former:

```
fuelInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(fuelprefab, initial, Quaternion.identity);
yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range (1, 3));
spawning = false;
Destroy(fuelInstance, Random.Range(1,3));
```